# 3D Gaussian Filtering in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, 3d, filtering, gaussian

I am trying to implement a 3D Gaussian Filter in Matlab - WITHOUT using inbuilt Matlab filtering functions like *imfilter*, *imgaussfilt* etc...

---

I have a 3D data

```
RAW(K,K,K)
```

Say, `K = 100`, and filter width `delta = 5` for this example.

Currently, I have :

```
Ggrid = -floor(delta/2):floor(delta/2);
[X Y Z] = meshgrid(Ggrid, Ggrid, Ggrid);

% Create Gaussian Mask
GaussM = exp(-(X.^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2) / (2*delta^2));

% Normalize so that total area (sum of all weights) is 1
GaussM = GaussM/sum(GaussM(:));
```

Which gives me a 3D Gaussian Kernel of dimensions `K+1 * K+1 * K+1`.
Now, to get the filtered data, I want to do a convolution like :

```
FilteredData = conv(RAW,GaussM);
```

but there is a dimensional mismatch. Can someone point out where I am going wrong? I assume I am making some mistake in the Gaussian mask `GaussM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `conv` as this is for 1D signals.  Use [`convn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) for N-dimensional filtering where you can specify kernels of any dimension, including 3D.

As such, it's just a matter of:

```
FilteredData = convn(RAW, GaussM);
```

Also take note that the default operation is to provide an output that performs **full** convolution, meaning that the size of the output will be larger than the original size of `RAW`.  To ensure that the output of `convn` is the same size as `RAW`, specify the `'same'` flag as the third parameter into `convn`:

```
FilteredData = convn(RAW, GaussM, 'same');
```

Comment: Then there is something else that you're not doing properly. `convn` can comfortably do 3D data. Please post the exact error.

Comment: Tnx @rayryeng. `convn` did the N-Dimentional convolution. The, `same` flag kept the convolution to the `(K,K,K)` dimension. Did the job easier than I thought.

I did cycle through using `conv` and `convn`. Didnt quite know there was a flag I could use.